# Java 2D Game - I Don't Understand Some Code

Tags: java, class

```
BufferedImage image;
image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
```

I am currently making a 2D Java Game, as per an exercise in a course I am taking; however, there are a couple of things I do not understand here. The first thing I am not too sure about is:

```
SpriteSheet.class
```

I have never seen .class ever be used before. What exactly is it? Furthermore, why does just putting in path in the getResourceAsStream method work. Is it because I have the SpriteSheet in a res folder, which is in the program's build path.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/SpriteSheet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.class` refers to the `Class` object for a given class.

for example, `Integer.class` will refer to the `Class` object for `java.lang.Integer`.

`getResourceAsStream()` will return an `InputStream` pointing to a file in the current classpath.

Comment: Ok, so is path like a pre-define variable that refers to the current classpath? Also is a Class Object always automatically created for every class?

Comment: path is a variable that you've set previously in your code, it's not predefined. And yes, Class objects are automatically created for every loaded class by the JVM.

Comment: Ok, I pretty much understand. Thank's a lot!